# Given the following set of equations, find: $xy + 2yz + 3zx$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

> The positive reals x, y, z satisfy the equations
> $$x^2 + xy + \frac{y^2}{3}=25$$
> $$\frac{y^2}{3}+z^2 = 9$$
> $$z^2+ zx + x^2 = 16$$
> Find $$xy + 2yz + 3zx$$

---

**My understanding:**

---

1. What struck me first were the squares $9, 16, 25$. This is the “Egyptian triangle.” It is a hint to the theorem of Pythagoras, to geometry, and geometrical
   interpretation.
2. Instead of $x, y, z$ only $xy + 2yz + 3zx$ is required. This may be an area,
   maybe even the area $6$ of the Egyptian triangle. It is also a hint that I
   should not try to find $x, y, z$.
3. $\frac{y^2}{3}$ occurs twice, so it may be helpful to set $a^2=\frac{y^2}{3}$.

The equations finally become:

$$x^2+ \sqrt{3}xt + t^2 = 25$$

$$t^2+z^2=9$$

$$z^2+ zx + x^2 = 16$$

Also, one more observation, $zx$ must be a perfect square.

---

I am not sure if I'm on the right track, but I don't know how to proceed further. Hints and help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I get $\pm\sqrt{12^3}$ by grobner basis methods.

Comment: Check: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h78414p449357 for a geometric approach. Algebraic approach also possible, though more clumsy.

Comment: I have squared the expression.  All terms can be turned into terms involving just $x^2,y^2,z^2$.  I used $(2)$ to eliminate $y^2$, and $(3)$ got me to $1728+192z^2-81x^2$. Wolfram tells me that equals $1728$, but I can't justify that yet.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland The answers mention only $+\sqrt{12^3}$

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice the positive solutions only. a≈41.5692 ∧ x≈2.77926 ∧ y≈4.15018 ∧ z≈1.80518

Comment: In [M2](https://www.unimelb-macaulay2.cloud.edu.au/#home) `R=QQ[a][x,y,z]` `I=ideal(x^2 + x*y + y^2/3-25,y^2/3+z^2-9,z^2+z*x+x^2-16,x*y+2*y*z+3*z*x-a)` `gens gb I -- matrix {{a^2-1728, 32*y+(-a-32)*z, 27*x-a*z, 6553*z^2+432*a-39312}}`

Answer (score 2):

Adding the second and third equation and subtracting first equation , we get

$2z^2+xz=yx$

Substitute the value for $y$ in the first equation, we get

$$3x^4+7x^2z^2+3x^3z+4z^4+4z^3x=75x^2$$

which easily gets factored into

$$(x^2+z^2+xz)(3x^2+4z^2)=75x^2$$
$$(16)(3x^2+4z^2)=75x^2$$

One possible way to avoid all the algebraic mess is that on solving the above equation we get,
$z^2=\frac{27}{64}x^2$ you could take $a^2=\frac{27}{64}$. This simplifies the calculations a lot since $z=ax$ and $y=2a^2x+ax$

On subsitituting in second equation we get $27=4x^2(a^2+a^3+a^4)$

And we have to find $4x^2(a+a^2+a^3)=\frac{27}{a}$.

And we are done. Not the cleanest approach but it is a way if nothing else seems obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=xy + 2yz + 3zx.$

Second equation is the circle with parametric equations
$$y=3\sqrt3\sin t,\quad z=3\cos t$$
Adding the second and third equation and subtracting first equation , we get
$$2z^2+xz-xy=0,$$
$$x=\frac{2z^2}{y-z}=\frac{6\cos^2t }{\sqrt3\sin t-\cos t}.$$
Parametric expresions for $x,y,z$ we substitute in $f^2$. Trigonometric simplifications gives
$$f^2=-\frac{1458(\cos2t+1)}{\sqrt3\sin2t+\cos2t-2}.$$
From first equation
$$\cos2t=\frac{37-32\sqrt3\sin2t}{59}.$$
On subsitituting this in $f^2$ we get
$$f^2=1728$$
Then $f=\sqrt{1728}=24\sqrt3$.

For trigonometric simplifications I use CAS (Maxima, Maple, ...)